# Create Date.UTC from a string

Tags: javascript

I need to create a `Date.UTC` from a string in the format "20150317". `Date.UTC` accepts 3 digits. How can I do that instead of having to parse the input string manually and split it into 3 parts?

Comment: What's wrong with having to split the string into 3 parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parts = '20150317'.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
var utc = Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
```

Comment: you can show a quick example with add a snippet button :)

Comment: How to do that? I know how to make a example with JSfiddle, but your advice is about something other.

Comment: Oy, Pavel, Pavel, mozet eshe chto-nibud posloznee pridumaesh'?

Comment: Jawanam, My znakomy?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a regex to parse the custom date string, and convert it to a UTC Date object.

```js
function parseISODateToUTC(dateString) {
    var match = /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/.exec(dateString);
    return Date.UTC(Number(match[1]), Number(match[2]) - 1, Number(match[3]));
}

alert(parseISODateToUTC("20150417"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With moment.js you can create a moment object using the [String+Format constructor](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
date = moment('20150317', 'YYYYMMDD').toDate();
```

now, you can call any of the Date methods including Date.UTC on `date`

Comment: Great, I'll have to download moment js only to be able to parse the Date. Fantastic!

Comment: It might sound bit overkill but Momentjs makes working with dates in JS a breeze. It about 12kb download, so not too big.